# Prove the relations of the cardinality of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> - Let us define natural numbers in the following manner (also assume Peano Axioms), 
>     $$\varnothing=0\\n^{+}=n\cup\{n\}$$where $n^{+}$ is the successor of $n$.
> - Let $E$ and $F$ be two sets such that there exists a one-to-one correspondence between them. Then we say that $E$ and $F$ are equivalent and write $E\sim F$.
> - A set $E$ is said to be *finite* if it is equivalent to some natural number. This (unique) natural number is said to be the *cardinality* of $E$. We will denote this by $|E|$. To be precise, we have $E\sim |E|$.

The problems at which I am stuck are (assume $E$ and $F$ to be finite),

1. $|E\cup F|=|E|+|F|-|E\cap F|$
2. $|E\times F|=|E|\cdot|F|$

I thought to show that the complement of $m$ in $m+n$ is equivalent to $n$ but couldn’t show anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Induction and induction.

Comment: Induction on what?

Comment: On the cardinality of one of the sets, letting the other one be arbitrary.

Comment: Can you use the fact that $E\cap F=\emptyset\implies |E\cup F|=|E|+|F|$ or do you need to prove that as well?

Comment: I need to prove it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n\in\Bbb N^+$, let $J_n=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Suppose $E\cap F=\emptyset$, $|E|=m$, and $|F|=n$.  So there are bijections, $\phi:E\to J_m$ and $\psi:F\to J_n$.  Let $\theta:E\cup F\to J_{m+n}$ be defined by

$$\theta(x)=\begin{cases}\phi(x), & x\in E\\\psi(x)+n, & x\in F\end{cases}.$$

Because $E\cap F=\emptyset$, $\theta$ is well-defined, and it is pretty easy to show that it is a bijection.  Note, you'll need to deal with the case when either $E$ or $F$ is empty.

For (1) you can now use $E\cup F=(E\setminus F)\cup (E\cap F)\cup (F\setminus E)$, and $E=(E\setminus F)\cup(E\cap F)$, $F=(F\setminus E)\cup(E\cap F)$. For (2), use $E\times F=\bigcup_{x\in F} E\times\{x\}$. Notice each of these equations break up sets into disjoint unions.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{N}^+$?

Comment: $\Bbb N^+$ is the set of positive integers.

Comment: Though it is not written, it seems that we can assume that if $E\sim F$ then $|E|=|F|$. Right?

Comment: If it's necessary, it's not too hard to prove $J_n\sim J_m\iff n=m$. This would show that for finite $E$ and $F$, $E\sim F\iff|E|=|F|$.

Comment: So, is it not necessary? Then how do you conclude that (if $E\cap F=\emptyset$), $|E\cup F|=|E|+|F|$?

Comment: I'm not saying it's not necessary. What I'm saying is that if you don't already have that fact at your disposal, you can easily prove it.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying my doubts.